# updating kernel failed and initramfs errors

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, dpkg, initramfs

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic (4.15.0-91.92) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic (4.15.0-91.92) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-91-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 106: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 108: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
E: amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/zram7
I: (UUID=bcbd72b9-6f5b-48b1-84e4-669dd5486b40)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 8: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cpio: Exec format error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 2 gzip 0
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and here is some other output

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic (4.15.0-91.92) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic (4.15.0-91.92) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-91-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 106: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 108: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
E: amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/zram7
I: (UUID=bcbd72b9-6f5b-48b1-84e4-669dd5486b40)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 8: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cpio: Exec format error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 2 gzip 0
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic
```

and another one

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-88-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 106: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 108: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
E: amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/zram7
I: (UUID=bcbd72b9-6f5b-48b1-84e4-669dd5486b40)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 8: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cpio: Exec format error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 2 gzip 0
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic with 1.
```

can someone help

edit : after setting the RESUME variable to none

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-88-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 106: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: 108: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode: cpio: Exec format error
E: amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 8: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: cpio: Exec format error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 2 gzip 0
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic with 1.
```

Comment: i already tried to set resume variable to noresume but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: the -c is for creating new initramfs file , and i've tried -u for updating the current one, but no good also

Comment: `gzip --version`
`gzip 1.6`

Comment: `cpio is already the newest version (2.12+dfsg-6ubuntu0.18.04.1).`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: i'm using linux mint 19.3 based on ubuntu bionic 18.04 LTS

Comment: hold on a second , i think i found it :D

Comment: Hopefully you do.  We mainly support only Ubuntu here and its official flavors.  Unfortunately Mint is not an official flavor so these should be asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem was with the cpio package 
after trying

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall cpio gzip initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core
```

it worked :D
I've tried reinstalling `initramfs-tools` `initramfs-tools-core` before. and `gzip` was working fine so i think it was cpio because `cpio --version` was giving weird stuff before reinstalling it

---

Thanks for Terrance